# How to disable vertical mouse wheel swiper react

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm using [swiper](https://swiperjs.com/)

i created this with some customization

[image]

The problem is that even if i scroll vertically, slider changes the slides.
How can i disable vertical scrolling either with CSS or JS and the package itself?

here is my code

```
<MySwiper 
    slidesPerView={3}
    direction={"horizontal"}
    freeMode={true}
    
    style={{ overflow: "scroll", position: "relative" }}
    spaceBetween={100}
    mousewheel={true}
    className="mySwiper"
  >
    <SwiperSlide>
      <Slime></Slime>
    </SwiperSlide>
 </MySwiper>
```

Comment: This doesn't happen on the [demo](https://swiperjs.com/demos) pages, right? Are you perhaps doing some code magic? :P

Comment: Also IMO this behaviour is intended, as long as you are hovering over the carousel, so I'd keep it as a feature (unless it also happens when you scroll outside of the carousel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `forceToAxis:true` to `mousewheel` like so

```
mousewheel={{  
 forceToAxis: true,
}}
```

this makes swiper to ignore vertical scrolling.